# allocating space for pointer to array of pointers

Tags: c

Good day. I have this: MAP_ITEM **map  what I think is pointer to array of pointers (correct me if I am wrong please) and I have to allocate space for it. I can allocate space using malloc for 1 pointer, but have no idea how to do this. help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Learn the basics... answering this _very_ basic question would be proving you a disservice. If you don't yet know the difference between a pointer to a pointer, an array or an array of pointers, then you shouldn't be trying to allocate heap memory just yet IMO

Comment: yeah. that helped me so much. in documentation to malloc isn't ** even mentioned. really thank you . . .

Comment: That's why I said you should learn the basics: `*` is a pointer, `**` is a pointer to a pointer. If you don't know about that, and how to work with double indirection, then you ought to stay clear of this stuff. First come to terms with what a pointer actually _is_, how you use them and _what they are actually for_.

Comment: good. pointer to a pointer. now, problem is I have into map insert two dimensional array. this is where I am stucked. I can allocate pointer to basic array and work with it: int *pointer = (int *)malloc(size of(int)*numofelements);  but how do I allocate two dimensional array, create pointer and then access its elements?

Comment: (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * numofpointers)

Comment: and then loop for all elements of int** and allocate an int*

Comment: Yes you do otherwise it will return you a void*. which is completly different from a int* (just try to increment a void* and a int* and you'll see the difference, one jumps 1 byte and the other jumps sizeof(int) bytes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Here is an example***, written for use with char **, but you can modify for your purposes:

```
char ** allocMemory(char ** a, int numStrings, int maxStrLen)
{
    int i;
    a = calloc(sizeof(char*)*(numStrings+1), sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
      a[i] = calloc(sizeof(char)*maxStrLen + 1, sizeof(char));
    }
    return a;
}
```

***call it like this***:  (for array of 10 strings, each having maximum of 79 characters (leave one for NULL term)

```
char **arrayOfString;

arrayOfString = allocMemory(arrayOfString, 10, 80);
```

//

***You also need to*** free memory created with `allocMemory`

```
void freeMemory(char ** a, int numStrings)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
        if(a[i]) free(a[i]);
    free(a);
}
```

***Call it like this***:

```
freeMemory(arrayOfStrings, 10);
```

Comment: You are welcome.  `char **` are not trivial to manage, but with care, can be.

Answer (score 0):

Import the stdlib.h
Then use the malloc function.
Where is an example for a one dimentional array:

```
int* my_in_array = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * size_of_my_array);
```

Note that malloc receives the number of bytes you want to allocate, so sizeof will tell you how many bytes a datatype will need (in this case an int, but it can be used for chars, structures, ...) and then I multiplicate it by size_of_my_array, wich is the number of elements of my array.

Now, just try to se this for you case.

Comment: Note: you will need more malloc calls than just one

Comment: Also, where is another function that you should use: free(<pointer>) wich must be called to free the memory block that you allocated, although the operative systems does this in the end of the program, is good practice to release memory when you don't need it anymore.